# ¿Existe un término para la acción de ser autor intelectual de algo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

¿Cómo se le puede llamar a la acción de ser autor intelectual de algo? Por ejemplo, un político de un país extranjero que genera una fuerza/partido político en otro país para aumentar su influencia internacional.

Comment: *¿"Ser el cerebro detrás de..."?* No sé *una* palabra que exprese esta idea.

Comment: En algunos casos, cuando el autor pasa inadvertido,  se podría usar **cerebro gris** http://dle.rae.es/?id=8Kjc7uR 1. m. Persona que dirige una organización o una actividad y pasa inadvertida.

Comment: Esos ejemplos que estáis poniendo describen a la persona no la acción.

Comment: @blonfu: La pregunta es sobre la **acción**, como señalas, pero el ejemplo parece apuntar a la persona ("Por ejemplo, un político de un país extranjero que ..."), lo que justifica que haya confusiones

Comment: @blonfu Pero tienes razón, claro. Por eso no menciono otros candidatos como **mano negra**  o **mano oculta**

Comment: @yotanka El ejemplo que pone yo lo he entendido como una explicación de "autor intelectual". Aunque esos sinónimos que van saliendo también pueden ayudar a encontrar la repuesta

Comment: no creo que exista un termino concreto, en general el autor intelectual es el "ideador",  o tal vez  planeador, ya que el autor intelectual puede ser unicamente quien presenta la idea y desarrolla el plan.

Comment: Mi sugerencia: "mentor".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La acción que describes puede ser **injerencia**

> [4.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ld3rZOs) prnl. Entremeterse, introducirse en una dependencia o negocio.

La persona que ejerce esa *injerencia* puede ser llamado **artífice**

> [3.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3rLvGGi) m. y f. autor (‖ persona que es causa de algo).

Answer (score 5):

Normalmente usamos la expresión *estar detrás de* para esta idea. Así podríamos decir:

> Se cree que Vladímir Putin está detrás de los movimientos secesionistas de Crimea.

Comment: O sea, hasta donde sabes no existe una palabra específica para describir eso

Comment: No había entendido que buscaras una sola palabra. En ese caso, no, no tengo nada mejor que lo que han propuesto otras respuestas.

Answer (score 3):

Después de barajar varias opciones, como [**promover**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ULyG6Yb)

> 1. tr. Impulsar el desarrollo o la realización de algo.

[**fomentar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IAzM5Tz)

> 1. tr. Excitar, promover, impulsar o proteger algo.

o [**incitar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LEsm51s)

> 1. tr. Inducir con fuerza a alguien a una acción. *La publicidad nos incita al consumo.*

creo que la más adecuada podría ser [**instigar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ln53CtO)

> 1. tr. **Inducir a alguien a una acción, generalmente considerada como negativa.** *Instigaron al pueblo a pedir la dimisión del alcalde.*
> 2. tr. **Tramar o preparar con astucia algo.** *Una campaña de prensa instigó la caída del Gobierno.*

Comment: Te vote positivo pero me parece que el autor intelectual mas que inducir o fomentar o instigar está ordenando a alguien hacer algo

Answer (score 0):

No me quedó claro si buscas un verbo o un sustantivo.

> inventar / invento
>
> descubrir / descubrimiento, hallazgo
>
> fundar / fundación
>
> proponer / propuesta
>
> sentar las bases [de una teoría] / elaboración [de una teoría]
>
> establecer / definición (?)

En el contexto adecuado:

> dar a luz / incepción